# MySQL slow query and EXPLAIN gave strange answers

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm joining two tables. 
Table unique_nucleosome_re has about 600,000 records.
Another table has 20,000 records.
The strange thing is the performance and the answer from EXPLAIN is different depending
on the condition in the WHERE clause.
When it was 
WHERE n.chromosome = 'X'
it took about 3 minutes.
When it was
WHERE n.chromosome = '2L'
it took more than 30 minutes and the connection is gone.

```
SELECT n.name , t.transcript_start , n.start
 FROM unique_nucleosome_re AS n 
 INNER JOIN tss_tata_range AS t  
 ON t.chromosome = n.chromosome
 WHERE (t.transcript_start > n.end AND t.ts_minus_250 < n.start )  
       AND n.chromosome = 'X'     
 ORDER BY t.transcript_start
;
```

This is the answer from EXPLAIN.
when the WHERE is n.chromosome = 'X'

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'n', 'ALL', 'start_idx,end_idx,chromo_start', NULL, NULL, NULL, '606096', '48.42', 'Using where; Using join buffer'
```

when the WHERE is n.chromosome = '2L'

```
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'n', 'ref', 'start_idx,end_idx,chromo_start', 'chromo_start', '17', 'const', '68109', '100.00', 'Using where'
```

The number of records for X or 2L are almost the same. 
I spent last couple days but I couldn't figure it out. It may be a simple mistake I can't see or might be a bug.
Could you help me?

Comment: Sometimes the optimizer is bugged so you've some fuzzy results.

Comment: Can you try it on a different version? (I'm a slow writer)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other version available with me now. It is  MySQL server 5.1.49-1ubuntu8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, without seeing any index information, I would have an index on your TSS_TData_Range on the Chromosome key and transcript_start (but a minimum of the chromosome key).  I would also assume there is an index on chromosome on your unique_nucleosome_re table.  Then, it appears the TSS is your SHORT table, so I would move THAT into the FIRST position of the query and invoke use of the "STRAIGHT_JOIN" clause...

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      n.name, 
      t.transcript_start, 
      n.start  
   FROM 
      tss_tdata_range t,
      unique_nucleosome_re n
   where 
          t.chromosome = 'X'
      and t.chromosome = n.chromosome
      and t.transcript_start > n.end
      and t.ts_minus_250 < n.start
   order by
      t.transcript_start
```

I'd be interested in the performance too if it works well for you...

Comment: You're right in regarding indices. Chromosome in both tables and other keys in WHERE are indexed. I'll try it and let you know. :)

Comment: Hmmm,,, The first one took 17 secs and the second one took 37 secs when both limited by 10. I restarted the server before profiling to eliminate the cache.

Comment: @microbe good point on server refresh and cache, but I think you'll find it still somewhat consistent for you... Glad to help... some people don't realize the power that STRAIGHT_JOIN can do for you especially if you KNOW your data and the relationships...

Comment: Also I learned that in case of low cardinality, like in this case, select subset of the data may improve the performance. e.g. the first FROM will be FROM (select name, start from unique_nucleosome_re where chromosome = 'X') AS n.